# How to set table cell width and height in Bootstrap tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, datatables

I do not understand how Bootstrap table cells have a width greater than what I set via width, min-width, and max-width styles both in external styles and inline within the table cell. I am setting a width of 150px but the actual width is 218.25px.

```
table{table-layout:fixed;}
td, th{
width:150px !important;
height:75px !important;
max-width:150px !important;
max-height:75px !important;
min-width:150px !important;
min-height:75px !important;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/QK9sE0/b8on0vzj/14/

A screenshot below illustrates my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bootstrap` sets the `table` at 100% width, so you need to override that. Here is what I did:

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width: inherit !important;
}
td, th {
  width:150px !important;
  height:75px !important;
  max-width:150px !important;
  max-height:75px !important;
  min-width:150px !important;
  min-height:75px !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td style="width:150px; height:75px">Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, your approach gets me closer - https://jsfiddle.net/QK9sE0/npLe0adv/17/ - but strangely it's the height of cells now that I can't seem to control. The width is 150px now as set but the height is 100px instead of 75px as set.

Comment: Do you want **EVERY** box to be 150px X 75px (including `thead`)?

Comment: Yes. Shouldn't a style rule accomplish that?

Comment: I have updated my answer and description, so test it and let me know if that works!